# Acess Aws server files using FTP like filezilla without .pem file

Tags: server, ssh, aws, filezilla

My Manager sent me AWS server credentails and told me to connect with filezilla.

He gave the **Hostname** & **User : ubuntu** , but when i asked for **.pem or ssh key** file, he told my **system's key** is already added to the server. What he mean ? Without .pem file how can i connect to Server? Please guide me.

Comment: Your manager? If this is a corporate setup, does your company have some sort of SSO service in which you can add SSH keys? If so, have you added your key to that service already?

Comment: @muru before joining this company, my manager was using my laptop. and he said he already added the " my laptop key " to amazon aws server. so he said " no need to add key " . i don't have access to amazon instance.

Comment: You really should be asking your manager how to access that key then.

Comment: @muru i will ask , before that,  i wanted to make sure without adding .pem file to SFTP filezilla , we can not able to access files , right ?

Comment: No, not necessarily. That's one way of setting up authentication in EC2 instances, but you can skip that and add different keys after creating the instance (e.g., using cloud-init, or manually). Who knows, maybe your manager even configured Filezilla to use this key already

Comment: @muru so what i understood from your comment is :  " i can  create new ssh key from my system through putty and i can use that ssh key in filezilla and access the server files. i do not need .pem file from my manager." please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, provided your manager has added the public key you created to the EC2 instance.

Comment: @muru yes as he was working in my laptop before, i am sure he created some key from my laptop and added that key to aws. but i installed filezilla.

Comment: @muru as my manager already added my public key, now i need to create new private ssh key through putty and i need to add that as ssh key at the time of connecting in filezilla, right ?

Comment: A public key and a private key are created together as a pair. If your manager already added a public key, then there already is an existing private key that you should use. If you're going to make a new key pair, then your manager will have to add the public key from that pair instead,

Comment: @muru thanks for the clarification. i found one ppk file in my laptop. i will try with that and let you know the result.

Comment: once i add the correct private key, it worked for me, thankyou for your valuable time. you can post as answer.